# Definition of continuity implies some kind of subset

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Given $Z_n\rightarrow ^p b$, and if $g$ is continuous at $b$, then
> $g(Z_n)\rightarrow^p g(b)$.

That's the context of the problem, but my real issue is this. The definition of continuity is $\forall\epsilon\exists\delta:|Z_n-b|<\delta\Rightarrow |g(Z_n)-g(b)|<\epsilon$. This implies that $|Z_n-b|<\delta$ is a subset of $|g(Z_n)-g(b)|<\epsilon$. I'm struggling to understand why? If there are only some deltas such that the implication holds, isn't the implication a subset of the left side? Like say it holds for deltas below 5 and not for deltas more than 5. Then surely $|g(Z_n)-g(b)|<\epsilon \subseteq|Z_n-b|<\delta$? What's wrong with this reasoning, if anything?

Comment: "This implies that $|Zn−b|<δ$ is a subset of $|g(Zn)−g(b)|<ϵ$. I'm struggling to understand why?"  In other words, the things that are close to $b$ get mapped to things that are close to $g(b)$.  Does that not make sense?

Comment: I think I have gotten it through this thought process: Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there is $\delta>0$ such that $|Z_n-b|<\delta\Rightarrow|g(Z_n)-g(b)|<\epsilon$. For one of those delta, since this delta might not be the biggest such delta we have $|Z_n-b|<\delta\subseteq|g(Z_n)-g(b)|<\epsilon$

Comment: That's right.  And if some $\delta$ works, then $\delta/2$ also works.

Comment: To be precise, it's incorrect to say that it's a subset inclusion '$\subseteq$'.  But that is the  correct idea.

Comment: Gotcha! thanks!